# check if file exists then load else make a blank execution

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've a situation like this:
I've some files (csv) in a folder in azure blob container. The adf pipeline will check if the folder is available/exists then it'll simply execute/run the process to load data into sql table. But if the folder does not exists, then also the adf pipeline should execute without failing (making a dry/blank execution) the pipeline i.e. do nothing.
I did tried with using "Validation" activity and it gets timeout if the source path/source folder is not available/does not exists and adf pipeline do nothing but when I checked the azure "monitor" it says status "failed".
Is it possible to make a blank adf pipeline execution when there are no files/folders exists in source?

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below flow:
Getmetadataactivity (to check whether the file exists)
Then If activity : if file exists then proceed with flow else do nothing

Get Meta data activity :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nandan, but you forgot to attach the screenshots I guess...

Comment: Hey,
I missed out on the links and images.
I have edited my original answer.

Please mark it as answer if it resolved your query

Comment: Thanks, and I already tried this way and also I had bit different scenario but it worked...